# rdiff-backup: Backup whole folder instead of his contents

Tags: backup, rsync, rdiff-backup

I have a issue about a backup procedure with rdiff-backup. Let's say that i want to make a backup in the following way:

```
rdiff-backup foo /media/bar
```

When I do that, all the contents of "**foo**" are stored in "**/media/bar/**", but not "**foo**" itself. This is a problem to me because I want to backup multiple directories with the `--include-globbing-filelist include-list`  option, if I do this, all the contents of the folders listed in `include-list` will be messy in the destination folder.

With rsync, if I do:

```
rsync -a foo /media/bar
```

"**foo**" and all of his contents will be transferred to "**/media/bar**" instead of his contents only.

So, is there any way to backup "**foo**" instead of only his contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method 1

```
rdiff-backup foo /media/bar/foo
```

... just saying. ;-)

#### Method 2

Create an include list like this:

```
/home/me/foo
/home/me/other-foo
- /**
```

Then backup like this:

```
rdiff-backup --include-globbing-filelist include-list / /media/bar
```

In other words, tell `rdiff-backup` to backup *everything*, but then exclude everything you don't explicitly mention with the catch-all `- /**` rule at the foot of the include file.

My example starts at the root directory, but you could start at any level you like:

```
/foo
/other-foo
- /**
```

and

```
rdiff-backup --include-globbing-filelist include-list /home/me /media/bar
```

I like to start at root because a) it gives me maximum freedom to include and exclude stuff later, and b) I'm backing up some files from `/etc` anyway.

Comment: I had thought in the first method, but have multiple directories to back up (ie would have to make a rdiff-backup call for each directory) and I wanted to keep a single history for all directories, then the first method would not a solution. The second method works for me and gave me a better understanding of inclusion lists, thank you. Just one question, the `-` is required in the last line of the include-list file? If so, why?

Comment: The leading `-` says that this line is an *exclusion*. Without that it'll include everything.

Comment: Basically, for *every* file in your tree you have to start at the top of the file and work down until you find a pattern that matches. If that pattern starts with `-` then it'll *exclude* it. Otherwise, or if no pattern matches then it'll *include* it.

Comment: Hm, things may have changed since this answer was written, for "My example starts at the root directory, but you could start at any level you like" - I'm trying to sync from `/home/me`, same kind of `/foo` syntax in the include-globbing-filelist file, and I get "Warning: file specification 'b'/**'' in filelist ... doesn't start with correct prefix ... Ignoring"